# Custom Meta Field - Remove comma from string with str_replace

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have a website that display car/vehicle listings. Each listing displays the **PRICE**. The price is set as a custom field on a custom post type, that is set to a string data type. The user typically types the price in as like **8,999**. I need to echo/output/display the data with the comma removed, like this: **8999**

Currently I display the data like this:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "_price", true); ?>
```

How can I use str_replace to output this data without the comma? Or is there a simpler, better way? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `$price = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_price', true ); echo str_replace( ',', '', $price );` would do it.

Comment: @SallyCJ I literally just figured this out on my own. Very similar to your answer. Thank your help. Ill post my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Literally just figured this out on my own by reviewing str_replace documentation again.

```
<?php
  $price_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_price", true);
  $price_meta_stripped = str_replace(',', '', $price_meta);
  echo $price_meta_stripped;
?>
```